# Problems with wordpress "Could not create directory"

Tags: wordpress

I have the theme Cera installed on my WordPress and already set the wordpress directories and files with the correct privileges like 775 to directories and 664 to files, like

drwxr-sr-x+  9 www-data www-data   421888 abr 28 09:58 wp-content/

When i tried  to install any plugins this error appears:

"Installation failed: Could not create directory. /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/upgrade/classic-editor.1.6.3/classic-editor".

I have a Linux Ubuntu server hosting the site.

For install plugins and thema i used the winscp for pass de the zips and unzip in the server.

What I need to do to permission to make directories?

Edit

Its possible the owner www-data have any problem with the privileges? Or apache2 cant access corretly?

Maybe the proxy can be the problem? Need to open any port or anything to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the plugin manually; upload it to the `wp-content/plugins` directory using FTP.

Although you mentioned that you've already set the correct file permissions, it's possible that the directories are still not writable by the server.

- Run `ls -la /var/www/html/wordpress/` command to check the ownership of the `wp-content` directory *AND PERHAPS* change it using `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress/`.

Hope you can resolve your issue soon!

*p.s. - make sure you have disk space, maybe you are max quota too*

Comment: Yes, i already try this, when i execute ll for see the permissions they are right